# How to add another array first to the lexicographically sorted array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, sorting, vue.js

I have lexicographically sorted an array. Is sorted like as:

```
const cityOfTheMoscow = ['Москва','Апрелевка', 'Балашиха',  'Видное',  'Воскресенск', 'Дзержинский', 'Дмитров', 'Долгопрудный', 'Домодедово',
      'Дубна', 'Егорьевск', 'Жуковский', 'Истра', 'Клин', 'Коломна', 'Королёв', 'Лыткарино', 'Люберцы', 'Мытищи', 'Наро-Фоминск',
      'Ногинск', 'Одинцово', 'Орехово-Зуево', 'Подольск', 'Протвино', 'Пушкино', 'Раменское', 'Реутов', 'Сергиев Посад', 'Серпухов',
      'Солнечногорск', 'Старая Купавна', 'Ступино', 'Фрязино', 'Химки', 'Чехов', 'Щелково', 'Электросталь']

const result = response.data
          result.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.Name > b.Name) { // 
              return 1;
            }
            if (a.Name < b.Name) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          });
          self.resultZips = result
```

How would I add values ​from an array "cityOfTheMoscow" firstly, and then lexicographically? I tried to do like as:

```
result.unshift(...self.cityOfTheMoscow)
```

It works, but cityOfTheMoscow it's just array with one value, and result its object in which there is a "Name" property

**update**
my result array looks something like this:

```
0: {
   Code: 0,
   CountryCode: 131,
   Region: 'Ростовская обл',
   Name: 'Ростов'
},
...
43: {
Code: 412,
CountryCode: 123,
Region: 'Московская обл'
Name: 'Москва'
}
```

In this array there are already cities that are in the array of cityOfTheMoscow, but sort order is needed exactly such that the first values ​​in the array are those values ​​that are specified in the array cityOfTheMoscow

Comment: Can you please clarify, what exactly you want, and clarify what exactly you want as output, what I am able to understand is first you want cityOfTheMoscow and then add all results , and all should be lexographically sorted by Name in results and strings in cityOfTheMoscow, is that so?

Comment: Please update the question with sample `response.data` and expected output.

Comment: Maybe this `cityOfTheMoscow.concat(result.map(({Name}) => Name))` ?

Comment: To change your original array, use cityOfTheMoscow.sort()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#concat` to concat both `cityOfTheMoscow` and `result` array. Since you only want to add the value of `Name` key, you can use `array#map` to create an array of `Name`.

```
[].concat(cityOfTheMoscow, result.map(({Name}) => Name))
```

Updated code :

```
const cityOfTheMoscow = ['Москва','Апрелевка', 'Балашиха',  'Видное',  'Воскресенск', 'Дзержинский', 'Дмитров', 'Долгопрудный', 'Домодедово',
  'Дубна', 'Егорьевск', 'Жуковский', 'Истра', 'Клин', 'Коломна', 'Королёв', 'Лыткарино', 'Люберцы', 'Мытищи', 'Наро-Фоминск',
  'Ногинск', 'Одинцово', 'Орехово-Зуево', 'Подольск', 'Протвино', 'Пушкино', 'Раменское', 'Реутов', 'Сергиев Посад', 'Серпухов',
  'Солнечногорск', 'Старая Купавна', 'Ступино', 'Фрязино', 'Химки', 'Чехов', 'Щелково', 'Электросталь'];

const result = response.data;
result.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.Name > b.Name) { // 
          return 1;
        }
        if (a.Name < b.Name) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
const resultZips = [].concat(cityOfTheMoscow, result.map(({Name}) => Name));
```

```js
const cityOfTheMoscow = ['Москва','Апрелевка', 'Балашиха',  'Видное',  'Воскресенск', 'Дзержинский', 'Дмитров', 'Долгопрудный', 'Домодедово','Дубна', 'Егорьевск', 'Жуковский', 'Истра', 'Клин', 'Коломна', 'Королёв', 'Лыткарино', 'Люберцы', 'Мытищи', 'Наро-Фоминск','Ногинск', 'Одинцово', 'Орехово-Зуево', 'Подольск', 'Протвино', 'Пушкино', 'Раменское', 'Реутов', 'Сергиев Посад', 'Серпухов','Солнечногорск', 'Старая Купавна', 'Ступино', 'Фрязино', 'Химки', 'Чехов', 'Щелково', 'Электросталь'],
      data = [{Name: 'Ростов'}, {Name: 'Москва'}, {Name: 'Щелково'}, {Name: 'Клин'}];
data.sort((a,b) => (cityOfTheMoscow.indexOf(a.Name) + 1 || Infinity) - (cityOfTheMoscow.indexOf(b.Name) + 1 || Infinity));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I guess it should be the other way round `[].concat(cityOfTheMoscow.map(Name => ({Name})),  result)`

Comment: it's work, but array cityOfTheMoscow contains simply the name of the cities that are already in result.

This is also sorted, but it turns out that api gives an error, because result is an object where one of the properties has the Name property, and the cityOfTheMoscow array is the values ​​that should be in the Name property

Comment: @georg This works, but then an object with a single Name property is obtained ... In addition to this property, there must be all properties from the array result

Comment: @StockholmSyndrom Do you want to have unique city name in your resultant array?

Comment: @HassanImam

Not really. Let's simplify the task.
I have an array of objects called result. It has one of the properties - Name. He also has a city with a name that is in the array of cityOfTheMoscow. And all other values ​that are in the array of cityOfTheMoscow are in the array "result". I created the array of cityOfTheMoscow only in order to determine the sort order. So, how to sort out the array in such a way that would be first the city of 'Moscow' (the very first one in the array of cityOfTheMoscow '), and then all the other cities already lexicographically sorted?

Comment: @StockholmSyndrom added the code snippet to sort your `result` array based on your `cityOfTheMoscow` array. The proposed solution will move the city not present in the `cityOfTheMoscow` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat method:

```
const newArray = cityOfTheMoscow.concat(result);
```

[Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
const cityOfTheMoscow = ['Москва','Апрелевка', 'Балашиха',  'Видное',  'Воскресенск', 'Дзержинский', 'Дмитров', 'Долгопрудный', 'Домодедово',
      'Дубна', 'Егорьевск', 'Жуковский', 'Истра', 'Клин', 'Коломна', 'Королёв', 'Лыткарино', 'Люберцы', 'Мытищи', 'Наро-Фоминск',
      'Ногинск', 'Одинцово', 'Орехово-Зуево', 'Подольск', 'Протвино', 'Пушкино', 'Раменское', 'Реутов', 'Сергиев Посад', 'Серпухов',
      'Солнечногорск', 'Старая Купавна', 'Ступино', 'Фрязино', 'Химки', 'Чехов', 'Щелково', 'Электросталь'];

const sortedArray=cityOfTheMoscow.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.Name > b.Name) { // 
              return 1;
            }
            if (a.Name < b.Name) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          });
const newArray = cityOfTheMoscow.concat(sortedArray);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: my example `result.unshift(...self.cityOfTheMoscow)`  does the same

Comment: You want to sort the array with your sort function and then append it after the cityOfTheMoscow array. Isn't that correct?